# Kivy Screen Blank No buttons are getting displayed

Tags: python, kivy

Pls help. I'm trying to learn the basics but it won't display exactly as I expected it to. Only blank screen appears and no button. importing button also does not help.

main.py

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
[enter image description here][1]
class NoobWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


class NoobApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return NoobWidget()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    NoobApp().run()
```

kivytesta.kv

---

```
<NoobWidget>
  Button:
    text:"Click me"
  Label:
    text:"Not Clicked Yet"
```

Comment: Why do you have a [enter image description here][1] in your code?

Comment: sorry must have gotten pasted when I tried to paste a screnshot.

Answer (score 0):

You must load the `kv` file:

```
class NoobApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('kivytesta.kv')
        return NoobWidget()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the suggested fix advised but after installing python on a new laptop, I saw in the release notes that back then that latest version of kivy was not compatible to the python 3.x version I was using.  Now I am using the latest version of Kivy 2.0.0 and it worked.